# MariaDB unicode text got truncated

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using 5.5.40-MariaDB in Centos 7.

```
[root@test ~]# /usr/libexec/mysqld -V
/usr/libexec/mysqld  Ver 5.5.40-MariaDB for Linux on x86_64 (MariaDB Server)
```

I'm trying to insert a unicode string into TEXT column like:

Perl:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE INTO Test (`Val`) VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute( uri_unescape('%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%96%D7%99%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%98/328-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A1-%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%98-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%') . ' -- A' );
```

Php:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE INTO Test (`Val`) VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute( array(urldecode('%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%96%D7%99%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%98/328-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A1-%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%98-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%') . ' -- A') );
```

Then in MySQL, it is:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Val                                                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| מוצרים/הסקה-מרכזית/פלט/328-מאביס-פלט-לבוילר-חי                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The ' -- A' is not inserted at all. (both Perl and PHP have the same result so it should be a bug in MySQL itself?)

If I remove the last '%D7%' in url, then it will be inserted as

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Val                                                                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| מוצרים/הסקה-מרכזית/פלט/328-מאביס-פלט-לבוילר-חי -- A                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So is there any magic for %D7% (or just %D7)? how to fix that in MySQL? any my.cnf settings?

Table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `Val` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Where does `uri_unescape()` come from?

Comment: that's from Perl 'use URI::Escape;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting utf8 strings, an invalid byte combination will cause truncation.

You have two different functions; I assume one blindly left a D7 at then end, leading to truncation; and the other stripped it off?

Comment: why D7 will lead a truncation? any magic here?

Comment: In correctly formed utf8, hex D7 _must_ be followed immediately by another byte with the high bit on.  If it is not, then it is invalid utf8, and the code does what it feels like.  Perhaps replace it with '?', perhaps truncate the string, perhaps throw an error.  I'm suggesting that your two _different_ function calls are doing two _different_ actions.